# EditText In ListView

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <!-- Header -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/heading"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Items"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#CC6633"
            android:textSize="25px"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button
            android:text="Add To Order"
            android:id="@+id/btnOrder"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="15px"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtnameItem"
                android:text="Item"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtpriceItem"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Price"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left">
            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtorderItem"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Order"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- List Divider -->
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:background="#C85A17" />

    <!-- ListView (list_items) -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**finalorderitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="#FFFFFF"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="15dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:paddingRight="0dip"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtnameFinalOrderItem"
                android:textSize="20px"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="col_1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <EditText
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/edttextFinalOrderQty"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="setFocus"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </EditText>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtfinalpriceFinalOrderItem"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="col_2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="20px"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

so now i make a CustomAdapter which extends BaseAdapter class, all things work very fine, list view appear correctly, but whenever i click on edittext to enter some value then it lost his focus due to getView() function, so please suggest me what can i do for this

Comment: please any one who knoes about it, then reply, i am also facing same problem

Comment: Try it.. Please Don't set the onclick listener for List View .... Lemme know if that works

Answer (score 2):

You can add a windowSoftInputMode description in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity 
android:name= "YourActivityName" 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
/>
```